# How to turn a square looking mesh to a circular mesh?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model the following part of this wheel:

[image]

So far, what I have is squarish (object contains mirror and subdiv modifier):
[image]

The question is, how can I model that part of the mesh to be circular like the one in the reference photo?

**UPDATE**

Created the following edges to support the cylinder edges and included an edge loop.
[image]

No issues when applying subdiv.

Front:

[image]

Back:

[image]

Side:

[image]

Comment: What is this model used for? Does it need to be a single connected mesh sharing the same modifier? Seems like it would be easier to model it out using multiple shapes

Comment: Hi, this model is for learning how to model. Depending on how far I can get, I might try to make a short animation out of it. I wasn't sure what would be the correct approach (single mesh or adding another shape for that part). So far,  the answers are leaning towards using another shape so I'm going with that approach.

Comment: Please check my answer, if it doesn't fix your current topology please share your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Original geometry

There is function to turn square looking meshes into circular.

`View3D` > `Mesh` > `Transform` > `To Sphere` or `Alt` + `Shift` + `S`
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/to_sphere.html

But it does not take the mirror modifier into account, would need more geometry than a square and topology is not nice for the subdivision surface modifier.

##### Joining primitives

You are better off deleting the square part, inserting an actual cylinder in that place, merging it with the main model with the `Boolean` modifier with the `Union` option.

[image]

Then selecting the edge of the connection between them add `Bevel` with at least 2 segments and then manually clean up the geometry with vertex `Merge` tool when they are getting too close to each other.

[image]

You might also need `Knife` to add supporting edges to relax normals when faces are displaying with stretches. Sometimes it is better to leave N-gons, sometimes - to add an edge. There is also an option to transfer normals from the original meshes.

[image]

You might at first practice joining just 2 cylinders.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and reference, but I think, for this answer to get better reception, you  should demonstrate how the operator can be used in this particular case, ideally winding up with decent topology. That's not immediately  obvious.

Comment: Thanks very much.. Very good fix :)

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I'm practicing your method before using it and I'm having trouble replicating your result (sorry, still a beginner). 

I started off using the Boolean modifier, which I applied to the circle and chose the cylinder as the target. Both shapes were joined but I can still see the bottom half of the cylinder remains. I don't see that from yours? Also, how were you able to see the edges of the cylinder? I'm in Edit mode and I can only see the edges from the circle. You can check my modifier settings and result in my post. I just add it.

Comment: Have you applied the Boolean modifier. Sorry if that was not obvious but to edit the geometry produced by a modifier you have to apply it, the same as with the mirror modifier you have used. If you had applied the modifier you should also hide or move a way the Boolean target object as it remains in the same place.

Comment: Oh, right! I can see the verticies now and I'm guessing you deleted the bottom face of the cylinder next to get rid of that bottom half, right? Now, for the beveling step, I don't entirely understand what you did. Which connected edges did you bevel? I have these edges selected and beveled (see my updated result). I then merge the verticies that are close to each other and delete the extra ones.

Comment: The edge that is produced by the intersection of the meshes needs to be beveled to resolve shading artifacts and to make it look natural. Not the edges of the cylinder.

Comment: Ok, I got the beveling part down and I thought my merging was fine until I applied a subdiv modifier (see my update). How did you merge yours?

Answer (score 2):

Create a 32 vertex cylinder and a 16 vertex circle, use the circle as knife project tool:

[image]

Clean the topology a bit, mirror (don't forget to enable the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier):

[image]

Extrude on Z:

[image]

Rework the topology a bit, bevel:

[image]

Edit: For your current topology, create these edges:

[image]

Edit 2: Extend the inner edge loop:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for following up on this. I really appreciate your patience and help. I created the edges like you said and it works perfectly. You can see my update.

Comment: See my second edit, extend the edge loop

Comment: Oh, I subdivided the front edge earlier to connect but an edge loop sounds better. I'm curious as to why though. Updated my topology - check my post.

Comment: it prevents the bad artefacts that could happen with an ngon